# Factory Pattern within XPath

Tags: java, xslt, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement an XSL-Stylesheet that accesses a toString()-Method of a TextExtractor. The parser I'm using is Saxon9HE.

Simple Classdiagram:

```
AbstractText
+toString() : String
```

```
Factory
+load(String uri) : AbstractText // Returns a instance of a subclass
```

Has anyone a clue how to call toString() within a xsl-file?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Whenever you want to process datatypes outside [Infoset](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/), [XDM](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/) or [XML Schema Datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) scope, you need to use [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Extension-Functions) or [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#extension-functions)extension functions

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about calling Java from XSLT, right? The rules for that depend on which XSLT processor you are using, which you haven't told us.